# Suddenly Comments Plugin code is not showing commenting box

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am using bellow code for comments:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-numposts="3"
     data-href="HERE_UNIQUE_URL" data-width="100%"
     data-order-by='reverse_time'>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=APPID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

Suddenly, It is not showing comments box on new url(data-href). while it is showing  with some old URL with comments message. Code are same. There have no error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Use "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/" and debug your new URL.
Maybe this is an issue from Facebook comment plugin for the new URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).